# "Expression Used in the condition always yields the same result" warning in C

Tags: c, if-statement, expression, boolean-logic, misra

I want to know what exactly the meaning of `Expression Used in the condition always yields the same result` Misra warning. Here is the piece of code i am using.

```
#define bool_new_timer_val    (Time_cnt < 4sec)

if( (bool_new_timer_val == True) ||
    (mystruct.bool_u8_status1 != 0x0) ||
    ((mystruct.bool_u8_status1 == 0x0) && (bool_old_timer == True)) ||
    (mystruct.bool_u8_status2 == True) ||
    (mystruct.bool_u8_status3 == True))
{
   // update the logic
}
```

While running Misra, i am getting the warning as `Expression 'mystruct.bool_u8_status1' used in the condition always yields the same result`.
The issue is pointing to the line `((mystruct.bool_u8_status1 == 0x0) && (bool_old_timer == True))`

I would like to know what is this warning means. My guess is that the value `mystruct.bool_u8_status1` always set as `0x0`. Is this correct understanding ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is `True`? What are the types involved?

Comment: Can the Misra checker deduce that `mystruct.bool_u8_status1` has always the same value, by something before that `if`? -- Does the Misra message include a line number? If so, you could say which of both expressions are meant.

Comment: True is a boolean value.

Comment: True is a boolean value , which will check the value is either True/False. Updated the line number also.

Comment: I get confused by `4sec`, because I get the impression that it cannot ever be successfully compiled. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Suggestion: replace the long condition with a function call: `if (needs_updating(&mystruct, bool_new_time_val, bool_old_timer)) { /*update the logic*/ }`

Comment: As an aside, when blaming MISRA for poor code, it's always useful to cite the Guideline you are in breach of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
(mystruct.bool_u8_status1 != 0x0) ||
((mystruct.bool_u8_status1 == 0x0) && (bool_old_timer == True)) ||
```

If `mystruct.bool_u8_status1 != 0x0` evaluates to TRUE, the second line isn't evaluated.

If `mystruct.bool_u8_status1 != 0x0` evaluates to FALSE, the code is equivalent to

```
(FALSE) ||
((TRUE) && (bool_old_timer == True)) ||
```

which in the end is simply

```
((bool_old_timer == True)) ||
```

So try writing the code like:

```
(mystruct.bool_u8_status1 != 0x0) ||
(bool_old_timer == True) ||
```